# Can a woman after puberty be called "Saghira" (صغيرة)?

Tags: fiqh, tafseer, arabic-translation, definitions

Greetings to the site members!

I wanted to ask about the word "saghira" (صغيرة).

Does this word have any other meaning than "child", "little", "girl"?

What is the approximate age range? Girl 15, 18, 20 years old can be called "saghira" in any cases?
**Can a woman after puberty be called "saghira"?**

Give your answer from the point of view of the Arabic language and Islam.

Comment: Salam and weclome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. The answer is yes.

Comment: Forgive me, I did not understand you.
Can you answer in more detail, please?

Comment: If not difficult, give examples from dictionaries or words of Islamic scholars.

Comment: Well your question appears to be a bit broad there are several options for other meanings in this regards.

Comment: I don't know how to make it even shorter yet. I am wondering what age range this word might cover and if it is valid after puberty.

Please write down other variants of the meaning of this word (except for "child").

Comment: Give a sign, should I expect an answer to my question?

Comment: Apparently, you shouldn't wait for an answer.

Comment: What are you waiting for your re-phrased and focussed question got an answer, the original version was too broad as the word saghirah means small/little (female) in Arabic it has multiple meaning depending on the context.

Comment: That's what I'm asking about:
"it has multiple meaning depending on the context".

What are these meanings? Can you give examples?

Comment: And where is the answer to the question?

Comment: "And where is the answer to the question?" look down in the answer section and read if your question was "Can a woman after puberty be called "saghira"?". Else this question must be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

In the books of fiqh,  صغير and صغيرة are used to refer to pre-pubescents, I.e. those who have not displayed one of the signs of puberty and haven't yet reached 15 lunar years of age.

Comment: So this word has no other meanings than this?

They wrote to me above that there are other options. But he didn’t say which ones.

Comment: @ibn e Khan Can you share a reference to the source about the 15 lunar years of age?

Comment: @ggkhj When used in the context of fiqh, then it is used only for pre-pubescents, to distinguish from those who are pubescent. This is why you see scholars mention that it is permissible for the father to perform the nikāh of his صغير and صغيرة children by ijmāá.

Comment: @Ahmed Sure, this can be found in the books of fiqh, one such example is in Mukhtasar al-Qudūrī, a book of Hanafī fiqh:

“Abū Yūsuf and Muḥammad, may Allah have mercy on them, said that when the boy and the girl have completed fifteen years of age then they have attained puberty.”

Comment: Why then was Fatima called "saghira" in the hadith, if she was 15 years old or more at the time of her marriage?

Comment: There is difference of opinion regarding her age at the time of her nikāh, some opinions say she was 9.

Comment: Yes, the age of 9 is accepted by the Shiites.
Among the Sunnis, she was usually significantly older at the time of marriage.

Comment: And where is the answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

This question is exceptionally broad because صغير / صغيرة just means "small" or "little."

As such, it can be used in different contexts differently. A woman past puberty when being compared to an older woman for example could be considered small in comparison.

The meaning of the word is essentially to do with the context and comparison.

Often, in different contexts like fiqh, they may have a specified meaning of the word. In fiqh, people might often use it to refer to girls below puberty.

Comment: Can you give examples when this word was applied to sexually mature women?

Comment: @ggkhj https://sunnah.com/nasai:3221 Here, the meaning is she is much younger compared to Abu Bakr and Umar, but Ali (RA) was closer to her age.

Comment: I already know about this. Are there other examples?

Comment: @ggkhj I don't have any other examples in mind. One example is enough to demonstrate it.